# How to implement the UIView with fixed right margin and flexible left margin?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I want to make a view with fixed width, fixed right margin, and flexible left margin. From the document, I chose to use `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin`, but it presents flex margin left proportionally meanwhile flex margin right, and fixed width. That is not like what the document says, How can we make a `UIView` with fixed right margin and flexible left margin and fixed width?
Thank you!
[image]

Comment: It's difficult to figure out what exactly has gone wrong from your (rather vague) description. It'll be easier if you post some screenshots demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Please post the piece of code?

Comment: Ask simply, how to put a button in a view with fixed right margin and flexible left margin and fixed width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation it says:

> **`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin`**
>   The view resizes by expanding or shrinking in the direction of the left margin.

I suppose you are not expecting the view to resize, but with this flag it will to precisely that.

In fact, your problem has nothing to do with resizing, because you do not want to resize the view. Instead you should make sure the `frame.origin.x` is set properly by overriding `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: The frame.origin.x is flexible, and right margin is fixed, how to do?Just as the picture presets.

Comment: You have to calculate the correct `origin.x` whenever the subviews are laid out.

Comment: You don't think so, but then again, you don't know. Please explain what you think the `layoutSubviews` override is meant for.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is using AutoLayout in interface builder, without any code.

[image]

Comment: But I'v not used the IB or the StoryBoard, what I can't understand is why it's easy to implement in IB but can not do with code?

Comment: It is very easy. See the other answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant why the information so little about this.I found the autolayout:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html